# Using inner component in a loop in Shopware 6 does not persist the values uniquely for each looped component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, shopware, shopware6

I am using a `v-for` over a custom component and passing the item as a prop. But the issue is that each component instance in the loop takes the same item prop. For e.g in the 1st loop a component field has text "abc", then the second looped component also will have the same "abc" text. If I change the text in the 2nd one, it changes in the 1st component too. Is there a way to make the prop unique for each loop ?

For e.g this is the code which calls the inner component:

```
<template v-for="(businesscase, index) in businessCase.fields">
    <custom-case-freetext-field @field-changed="updateFields"
                             :key="index"
                             @field-removed="removeFields"
                             :fields="businessCase.fields"
                             :index="index">
    </custom-case-freetext-field>
</template>
```

and inside this component I have a basic form

```
<sw-field :label="$tc('rma.modules.case.freetext.nameLabel')"
  :placeholder="$tc('rma.modules.case.freetext.nameLabel')"
  required
  v-model="fields[index].name">
</sw-field>

<sw-single-select
    labelValue="label"
    valueProperty="label"
    :options="fieldTypes"
    :label="$tc('rma.modules.case.freetext.fieldType')"
    :placeholder="$tc('rma.modules.case.freetext.fieldType')"
    v-model="fields[index].type"
    @input="changeType"
    required>
</sw-single-select>
```

If I do `:value` instead of `v-model`, the entered value disappears as soon as the element loses focus.

If I use `v-model`, the data stays there, but then both (or as many are there in the loop) component instances, have data binding between them, so it defeats the purpose of having a loop for multiple components. As seen in the screenshot, I am typing in the 2nd component, but it changes the text for the first one too.

[image: Data Binding Problem]

In the above example I am sending the whole array as prop, but I have also tried with individual `field` element instead of `fields`

Answer (score 0):

Your are not using the businesscase variable inside your components. And since every component always works on the upper scope property, they will all change the same. Use the innerscope property. If you have problems with reactivity, because you try to mutate props directly work with events emitting the key and the changed value to the upperscope component.

Comment: What do you mean by inner scope? As in instead of passing businesscase.fields, I send the whole businesscase as a prop?